# Roles see different top menu (nav menu)

Tags: menus, user-roles, admin-menu

I'm new to WordPress but has some knowledge in HTML, CSS and and a little of PHP. I'm trying to make a new menu in "top menu" that will be hidden to users that are not admin, but will appear to admin when signed in. Is there a plugin or such or do I need to hard code it? Advice(s) would definitely help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use this plugin for Roles see different top menu (nav menu)  :**

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/
```

Comment: Saw this way before the comment but thanks!